# Updating Redis hash safely

Tags: python, redis

I have a hash in redis. It has 20 key/value pairs. I want to update it hourly and remove old elements. What is the best way to remove HASH key's content and fill with with fresh values. Since HASH is part of an API, I don't want to cause any race condition when I am removing all elements from the HASH. I don't want to use `EXPIRE` because I want to have a control over schedule.

I created following mock up. Assume that `Faker()` is my API that gets fresh values. I want to add new values to HASH and get rid of the old ones.

```
    import redis
    import json
    from faker import Faker

    try:
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        fake = Faker()
        for _ in range(20):
            userId = fake.uuid4()
            user = {"name":fake.name(),"address":fake.address(),"country":fake.country()}
            r.hset('users',userId,json.dumps(user))

    except Exception as e:
        print ('Error',e)
```

Comment: Can you rename hashsets? if so, build a new one, and switch the name.

Comment: I can rename them but how the API clients will know the new hashset or how to get rid of old hashset. I don't want to cause any mess during renaming and removing.

Answer (score 4):

How about deleting the Hash with a `DEL` command? You can wrap it in a transaction that also sets (`HSET`) the new values in it.

Answer (score 0):

"What is the best way to remove HASH key's content and fill with with fresh values." just update it, at least if you're updating... so hset(hash, key, newvalue) or hmset(hash, newvalues_dictionary) - whats bad with this approach?

Comment: I want to get rid of old content. Old content must not exist after new content is added. when API clients ask for HSET they shouldn't get old content. If I add HSET when I ask for a set, it will also return the old ones.